# form field is already filled

Tags: php, mysql

Im a starter in PHP and my problem is like my form fields are already filled with root and password even without entering anything... please help...

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="****";
    $db="test123";
    mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass); 
    mysqli_select_db($db);
    if(isset($_POST['username']));
    {
        $username=$_POST['usern'];
        $password=$_POST['passw'];
        $qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".$username."' 
            AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1 ";
        $res=mysql_query($qry);
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($res)==1 )
        {
             echo"You have successfully logged in";
            exit();
            }
            else{
            echo"invalid login information";
            exit();
            }
                    }
    ?>
```

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="login.php">Username:
            <input type="text" name="usern">
            <br />
            <br />Password:
            <input type="password" name="passw">
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

.........................................................

OP:
Username: root
password: *******

Comment: Creating the three variables $username, $password and $qry is unnecessary. You could do that all in one line without it beeing cluttery. Using mysql_* functions is soon no longer supported and should be avoided. The way you use it is a huge security risk as you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Regarding the original question, try a different browser, you probably have some form fields cached.

Comment: Do you by chance have that saved in your browser after login in?

Comment: It just a browser feature, at the time of login did u save the password?, if yes it is not a problem and if no, clear the browser history, cache, then it will be ok for u.

Comment: Turn off form autocomplete in your browser as it is your browser filling it in not the code

Comment: Are you using value="<?php echo $user; ?>" in your form? Explain in detail

Comment: Changing the browser worked...Im sorry that was a stupid mistake..Thank you for your time

Comment: @JimL hey could you please tell me the alternative way that i should follow insted of mysql_* functions...like what should i use in here insted of mysql_

Comment: @RenMathew http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @JimL But Sir When I change everything it gives me warning mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass); 
mysqli_select_db($db);
$res=mysqli_query($qry);
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($res)==1 )                                       Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreamfiles\login.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreamfiles\login.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreamfiles\login.php on line 16
invald loin info

Comment: Learn how to search. I'm sorry, but you'll get nowhere if you stumble and fall if you get an error. A search on SO or Google will give you thousands of hits on how to fix that error. Also just changing to mysqli_query does not fix your sql injections. You have to use prepared statements and bind the parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest and simplest way to disable Form and Password storage prompts and prevent form data from being cached in session history is to use the autocomplete form element attribute with value `off`:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="usern" autocomplete="off"><br /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="passw" autocomplete="off"><br /><br />
```

This is another way to accomplish the same thing, but it disables auto-completion for all input elements and may not work on all browsers:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" autocomplete="off">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Whilst this technically works, it is not great from a user experience point of view to deliberately stop functionality from working that users are used to using.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your username field

```
if(isset($_POST['username']));
```

Change to

```
if(isset($_POST['usern']));
```

It will never go inside the If Condition.